# Need help in the recursive procedure call

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql

I have a requirement to write a procedure (that calls itself recursively).
The condition is like:

1. If the CONTACT NUMBER(assuming it as varchar2) STARTS WITH '100-%', then the procedure should print all the CONTACT NUMBERS that starts with 100 for the given group.
2. If CONTACT NUMBER starts with '50-%' then it should call recursively.

I have tried writing a sample procedure, but unfortunately not getting the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_t AS
    TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test (
    in_group       IN VARCHAR2,
    contact_nmbr   OUT VARCHAR2
) AS
    v_out   type_t := type_t ();
BEGIN
    SELECT
        contact_id
    BULK COLLECT INTO
        v_out
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        group_id = in_group;

    FOR i IN 1..v_out.count LOOP
        v_out.extend;
        IF
            v_out(i) LIKE '100-%'
        THEN
            contact_nmbr := v_out(i);
        ELSIF v_out(i) LIKE '50-%' THEN
            proc_test(v_out(i),contact_nmbr);
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

END;
```

/

I am not getting the output after running this proc.

```
DECLARE
    in_group       VARCHAR2(30) := '123ABC';
    contact_nmbr   VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    proc_test(in_group,contact_nmbr);
    dbms_output.put_line(contact_nmbr);
END;
```

/
This is the sample data in table MY_TABLE

```
Group_Id          Contact_Id
---------------------------------------
001               100-001-01
001               70-001-01
001               100-002-01
001               50-001-01
50-001-01         30-001-01
50-001-01         100-100-01
50-001-01         50-100-01
50-100-01         50-200-01
```

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the question tags and include the data in your table `MY_TABLE`. Thanks.

Comment: When you say not getting the result.... What exactly do you mean? Do you get nothing at all (could be you need to set server output on to get the dbms_output to display), do you get an error? do you get some results but not the results you want? For people to help we will need a bit more information.

Comment: I mean to say that whenever I am trying to call the procedure, I am not getting a single record. It might be due to recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues I can see with your script....

1) You are declaring the in_group to = 123ABC there is no data matching in your sample data so it will never return anything...

```
in_group       VARCHAR2(30) := '123ABC';
```

2) You do not exit the loop when you successfully find a contact number so unless your last record is a match you will get no output;

3) when you increment the v_out collection on each loop this serves no purpose this does not do any harm but is not necassary

```
  v_out.extend;
```

So remove the extend and add a exit as below....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test (
    in_group       IN VARCHAR2,
    contact_nmbr   OUT VARCHAR2
) AS
    v_out   type_t := type_t ();
BEGIN
    SELECT
        contact_id
    BULK COLLECT INTO
        v_out
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        group_id = in_group;

    FOR i IN 1..v_out.count LOOP
        IF
            v_out(i) LIKE '100-%'
        THEN
            contact_nmbr := v_out(i);
            exit;
        ELSIF v_out(i) LIKE '50-%' THEN
            proc_test(v_out(i),contact_nmbr);
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

END;
```

and call with a valid id as below and you should be good to go.

```
DECLARE
    in_group       VARCHAR2(30) := '001';
    contact_nmbr   VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    proc_test(in_group,contact_nmbr);
    dbms_output.put_line(contact_nmbr);
END;
```